# Changing one element in an multi-dimensional array changes all elements with values

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a program that lets a user put data into a multi-dimensional array, and display it as a table. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 5

int main(void) {
    int row, col;
    char *table[ROWS][COLS], text[11];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            table[i][j] = malloc(11);

    while (1) {
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%d %d %s", &row, &col, text);
        if (row > ROWS || col > COLS)
            return 1;
        table[row][col] = text;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
                printf("|%10s|", table[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can enter in a first value, and it will be stored properly, as so:

```
$ ./a.out
> 0 0 foo
|       foo||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
```

However, when I try to enter a second value, the first value is also changed:

```
> 0 1 bar
|       bar||       bar||          ||          ||          |
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
|          ||          ||          ||          ||          |
```

This continues if I enter in a third, fourth, fifth, etc. value; all of the values are changed.

Why is this happening, and how do I stop it from happening?

Comment: @tadman My apologies, I am new C, what is "undefined behavior"? Is there a way I can avoid it?

Comment: How many `text[11];` do you have? If you assign every element the same pointer (array/pointer conversion [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)), then all elements hold the same address as their value and in the end will all refer to whatever `text` contained last...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
table[row][col] = text;
```

You are *trashing* the value in `table` you previously got from `malloc` Any loop iteration will make the `table` value point to the *same* memory location (namely, `text`).

You want:

```
strcpy(table[row][col],text);
```

Also, your limit check for `row/col` needs `>=`

---

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 5

int
main(void)
{
    int row, col;
    char *table[ROWS][COLS], text[11];

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            table[i][j] = malloc(11);

    while (1) {
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%d %d %s", &row, &col, text);

// NOTE/BUG: the limit check is incorrect
#if 0
        if (row > ROWS || col > COLS)
            return 1;
#else
        if (row >= ROWS || col >= COLS)
            return 1;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: this blows away the value obtained from malloc
#if 0
        table[row][col] = text;
#else
        strcpy(table[row][col],text);
#endif

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
                printf("|%10s|", table[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Note that while the above works, it's a bit fragile.

If the text line entered was (e.g. `q`), the program goes into an infinite loop.

The value `11` is *hardwired*. Better to use a `#define` just like `ROWS` and `COLS`

There is *no* check for overflowing the `text` buffer.

I'd recode to use `fgets`, `strtol` and `strsep` because the error detection and recovery is so much better.

Also, the `malloc` preallocates a fixed array of `11`. If we're hardwiring that, we might as well dispense with `malloc` and do:

```
char table[ROWS][COLS][11];
```

Depending upon the final usage, it *might* be better to *not* fill `table` initially and only fill in elements as needed (i.e. initial value of `NULL`). Then, add elements using `realloc`.

Also, I'm not sure the format of the `printf` is exactly what you wanted (e.g. `||`).

So, I've generalized the code a bit more. Some of this may help a bit [and some may be too fancy for your use case]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS    5
#define COLS    5

int
main(void)
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int len;
    char **tp;
    char *bp;
    char *cp;
    int maxlen = 0;
    char buf[1000];
    char *table[ROWS][COLS];

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            table[i][j] = NULL;

    while (1) {
        printf("> ");

        // get next line -- stop on EOF
        bp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if (bp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline
        cp = strchr(bp,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        cp = bp;

        // get row number -- skip with garbage after it (e.g. 23x)
        row = strtol(cp,&cp,10);
        if (*cp++ != ' ')
            continue;
        if ((row < 0) || (row >= ROWS))
            continue;

        // get column number -- skip with garbage after it (e.g. 23x)
        col = strtol(cp,&cp,10);
        if (*cp++ != ' ')
            continue;
        if ((col < 0) || (col >= COLS))
            continue;

        // look for text
#ifdef WORDONLY
        // this skips internal whitespace (e.g. "hello world" --> "hello")
        bp = cp;
        cp = strsep(&bp," ");
        if (cp == NULL)
            continue;
#else
        // this preserves internal whitespace (e.g. "hello world")
        for (;  *cp != 0;  ++cp) {
            if (*cp != ' ')
                break;
        }
        if (*cp == 0)
            continue;
#endif

        // get the text length
        len = strlen(cp);
        if (len > maxlen)
            maxlen = len;

        // point to table entry
        tp = &table[row][col];

        // resize it (allowing for EOS)
        *tp = realloc(*tp,len + 1);

        // copy in the current buffer token
        strcpy(*tp,cp);

        char fmt[10];
        sprintf(fmt," %%%ds |",maxlen);

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            printf("|");
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                cp = table[i][j];
                if (cp == NULL)
                    cp = "";
                printf(fmt, cp);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```